# random <a> tags generated with outputLink through component

Tags: visualforce-component, outputlink

My component looks as such:

```
<apex:component layout="none">
    <ul class="chatter_links">
        <li class="like"><apex:outputLink value="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span><span class="count">9</span></apex:outputLink></li>
    </ul>
</apex:component>
```

When I display on the page, the html generated looks like this:

```
<ul class="chatter_links">
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <li class="like">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
            <span class="count">9</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I replace the `apex:outputLink` code with an `a href=""` it still does the same thing.  If I remove it completely and only have a list with the two spans, there are no additional tags created.

I am stumped.

Comment: Try just using an `<a>` tag instead of `<apex:outputLink>`.  Google "apex:outputLink" for the docs, and you'll see how Salesforce encodes the url from `<apex:outputLink>`'s `value` parameter

Comment: @amatorVitae I tried with an a tag as well, same result

Comment: Try wrapping both `<span>`s inside another `<span>` so they form a single unit.

Comment: @amatorVitae still no go!

Answer (score 1):

I was wrapping the component in an `<a>` tag.  Don't do that.  It doesn't currently work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Lex I am the author.  Unwrapping the component did solve my problem.

Comment: Right, sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention when reviewing. I'll upvote you to compensate ;)

Comment: @Lex you are kind beyond belief!